# Home.aspx: Change width of text layout from 50x50% to 65x35%

Tags: web-part-zone, webpart-width

I'm trying to modify width Firebug or in SPD, but don't see any changes affected to the page:

[image]

What should I change to resize left column from default '49.95%'? My text layout is this:

[image]

**upd.:** here I can get this zone and apply width attribute, but this doesn't change anything

```
var zone = jQuery("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").css({"width": "70%", "overflow": "auto"});
```

**upd2:** Ok, I created copy of Home.aspx in SitePages library, set it as "Welcome page", and there I was able to change column width using css, or inline styles in aspx file markup:

```
#layoutsTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) { width:64.95%;}
```

or something like this

```
var tr = jQuery("table#layoutsTable tbody tr").eq(2);
var td = jQuery(tr).find("td:first");
td.css({"width":"64.95%"});
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a new page layout? Use the one you're using at the moment as a starting point, take a copy of it and edit it to suit your needs. Then select your new layout (you may need to add your web parts to the page again).

Comment: Thank You for response! I suppose with custom page layout I will have the same problem. I don't understand what should I change to suit my needs( Publishing is on, I suppose it is not webpart page, but it is a Wiki page with RichEdit zones..

Comment: ..or You mean I will get additional control over this page and will be able to change these settings? Ok, thank You, I'll try!

Comment: If this is a wiki page then when you edit the page are you not able to adjust the width of that column?

Comment: It is the default page when You create Team Site for example. I changed "Text layouts" in ribbon to "Two columns with header and footer", and try to resize these columns. Yes I can't change the width anyway( I think I need to learn more about page layouts, design manager etc. I'll research and post results

Comment: Is this meant for a single page or do you want to replicate the same to other pages later on? Because if it is for a single page, you can always just add a css line within a code snippet webpart.

Comment: Hi Yugo! Yes, I prefer snippets too, but now I have dynamic webpart on the page and it was necessary to modify zones with inline styles..